# Insert does not happens because the procedure needs parameters

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have this query and it needs to only make a simple insert. but I face this error :

> Msg 8146, Level 16, State 2, Procedure InsertEducationCategory, Line 0
>   Procedure InsertEducationCategory has no parameters and arguments were supplied.

Any idea why this happens ?

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.procedures WHERE name = 'InsertEducationCategory') 
DROP PROCEDURE InsertEducationCategory
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE InsertEducationCategory
AS
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO Education_Category(Category_ID, Category_Name) VALUES(NEWID(), N'کاردانی')
   INSERT INTO Education_Category(Category_ID, Category_Name) VALUES(NEWID(), N'کارشناسی')
   INSERT INTO Education_Category(Category_ID, Category_Name) VALUES(NEWID(), N'کارشناسی ارشد')
   INSERT INTO Education_Category(Category_ID, Category_Name) VALUES (NEWID(), N'دکترا')
END
GO

EXEC InsertEducationCategory GO
```

Thanks

Comment: The `GO` on the EXEC is being interpreted as an argument. Try moving it to a separate line.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling a stored procedure that has no parameters but you are providing parameters when you call it.

If it had parameters, it would look like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertEducationCategory
     @Parameter1 nvarchar(5), -- or whatever type
     @Parameter2 int -- could be a different type...
AS
```

At that point, you could call `InsertEducationCategory('abcde', 16)`, but the way you have defined it, it only makes sense to call `InsertEducationCategory()`.

Comment: I know the meaning of that error sentence. what should I do to make this insert happens? I have more tables that have more columns. if this works correctly, then I can write others too. can you help me with this ?

Comment: the InsertEducationCategory() method does not work. I have no idea how to insert dummy data from one procedure to another:|
anyway, Thanks.

Comment: When I first read this, I didn't notice the `EXEC` call at the end. I thought you had omitted the actual call to the SP. SQLhint's answer is probably correct.

Answer (score 0):

"GO" on the last row is interpreted as argument of your SP. Just modify the line into:

```
EXEC InsertEducationCategory
GO
```